How can the 42180 Mars Exploration Rover be motorized?
The 42180 Mars Exploration Rover has a sturdy Technic frame with plenty of empty space - how could it be fitted with driving and steering motors for remote-controlled driving?

After receiving the rover via the 2024 Q1 Activity Support program, I set about to answer the question. Using parts from a 42065: RC Tracked Racer and a PF servo motor to keep the costs and complexity low I started by emptying the crew compartment to make room for the steering assembly, figuring there'd be no need for facilities for humans if the rover is remotely operated.
After hitting a snag with the servo motor, the plan changed to use a clutch for protecting the model and one of the PF M motors for steering. The first test with the clutch mechanism seen in the 42145 Airbus H175 Rescue Helicopter

proved the need for a setup with a higher slipping torque, so a Technic, Gear 24 Tooth Clutch has been chosen to proceed with.
Seeing the need for high torque, the power transmission from the motor to the steering axle was planned with a pair of Technic Knob Cog / Gear / Wheel with Axle Hole (+ Orientation) pieces. Finally, a 1:3 reduction gearing was added to allow for precision steering and to produce the torque required to turn the rubber wheels.

This was simplified later to eliminate the obvious redundancy still visible in this photo, see the final assembly stage for the latest version.
For the drive motor, a rear axle was constructed with the same knob gear (thanks to the clear round holes leading to the wheel hubs and no obstructions on the suspension), and a motor was mounted (here just temporarily) on some Technic-System bridge pieces:


This was enough to turn the wheels, albeit only in the upside-down orientation shown in the photos. As soon as the rover was resting on its wheels, the torque of the motor proved woefully inadequate to move the whole mass.
So for the next attempt a 1:8 reduction was added by changing the knob gears for the combination of a worm gear and an 8-tooth gear, while also strengthening the bracing around the transmission and moving the motor mounting a bit to the side and one unit further from the chassis (this sadly reduced the ground clearance significantly):

The battery box found a snug hiding place between the first and second axles (eliminating the wheelbase-changing function as collateral damage):

The steering motor was mounted on a plate held in the crew bay by several Technic pin 1/2s (the surplus seen here in grey):

Finally, the IR receiver was attached to the cargo area, with the cables routed via the airlock and a cutout in the payload bed:

Possible avenues for improvement would include:

Using stronger motors for more torque for both steering and driving
Mounting the motors in a more Technic-compliant and elegant way
Using a more modern RC architecture
Hiding the modifications better to keep more of the original functions, aesthetics, and playability.

